# Is there a hook/function in kivy to run once a widget has been added to the tree like onComponentDidMount

Tags: python, kivy

I am struggling with making reusable widgets in kivy. Specifically with the issue that when the widgets constructor is ran, the widget isn't part of the widget tree yet. So it won't have a parent, and if widget properties like the size, label or size_hint are defined in a kvlang file for the app, those values aren't available in the constructor for the widget either.

So my question is if there is a function or hook that I can run in a widget when the widget is added to the widget tree. Similar to how many html/javascript frameworks have an "onComponentDidMount" function for instance that gets called after the widget was added to the DOM. When this function is called, ideally its properties should be set from the kvlang builder/source app where it was used, it should have a parent and children, etc. At this point you could do the last modifications on the children, or the widget itself.

Comment: Every widget has a `parent` property that is observable. Perhaps you could bind to that property.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I will check. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The parent observable like mentioned by John Anderson does work for some cases, but I had a case where still some items weren't initialized. But what did work for me was the `Clock.schedule_once` method.
You can schedule a function to be called once, and if you do it with time 0, it will be ran at the next render of the screen, at which point all widgets have been initialized.

So this worked for me:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout


class SelectBox(StackLayout):
    """An html style select box"""
    label = StringProperty('Select an option')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.value = None
        Clock.schedule_once(self.onWidgetInitialized)

    def onWidgetInitialized(self, *_args, **_kwargs):
        """Do stuff once the whole widget has been initialized."""
```